# Can't find easing options in Adobe Edge

Tags: website-design

I just downloaded the adobe edge preview a few hours ago.

I can't seem to find the options for easing effects on transitions on the timeline. I click the transition, but the properties panel just stays like this:

[image]

I'm trying to follow this guide: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-slick-animations-adobe-edge

I don't know what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

The way to change transitions looks to have changed since that tutorial was written.

It's not in the properties panel any more. There's now an easing button down with the actual transitions on the timeline. Select a transition, click on it, and it'll give you options for the easing of that transition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are demonstrations of animation using easing functions on [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/introducing-adobe-edge-preview-5/). You'll also find examples of their use in the Edge samples that you can download from the same place.